# sklearn logistic regression parameter in GridSearch

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, logistic-regression

just wondering how to separate parameters into a group and pass it to gridsearch?
As i want to pass penalty l1 and l2 to grid search and corresponding solver newton-cg to L2.

However, when i run the code below, the gridsearch will first run l1 with newton-cg and result in error msg 
ValueError: Solver newton-cg supports only l2 penalties, got l1 penalty.

Thanks

```
 param_grid = [

  {'penalty':['l1','l2'] ,
   'solver' : ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga']
  }

 ]
```

Comment: add full code please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this example:

```
param_grid = [
  {'penalty': ['l1'], 'solver': [ 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga']},
  {'penalty': ['l2'], 'solver': ['newton-cg']},
 ]
```

here **l1** will be tried with **'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga'** and **l2** will be tried with only **'newton-cg'**

Comment: Solver lbfgs supports only 'l2'

Comment: Solver lbfgs supports only 'l2' and 'none'

Answer (score 2):

The official doc says:

> ... or a list of such dictionaries, in which case the grids spanned by each dictionary in the list are explored. This enables searching over any sequence of parameter settings.
>   So just supply a list of dictionaries each dictionary with consistent set of arguments that work together

There is also an explicit example in the `GridSearchCV` [User Guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#exhaustive-grid-search), which serves as a good example.